# How to avoid new line when the data is shown

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to know if is there a way to avoid a new line when the data is shown like this:

[image]

In order to show all in the same line with a crossbar, and easy to read.

Comment: Is it feasible to shorten your column names collectively by a combined 12 characters?  That would make it fit on one line, give or take a character or so?

Comment: And if you are not allowed to change the names, could you not just make a copy of this select as a view or something like that and do a SELECT AS (name) to temporary rename the columns to be shorter to fit this text size?

Comment: Such as possession_percentage could be "pos_pct" and that would give you more than enough and you can leave the other column names full length. '

Comment: are you using a databricks notebook?

Comment: @DerekO im using jupiter notebook

Answer (score 1):

You can display your dataframe vertically as well if that helps you

#### Vertical - Show

```
sparkDF.show(vertical=True,truncate=False)
```